# PHP: Can append to file but cannot echo the file contents properly

Tags: php

I am trying to create a local txt file, write some text inside, close it, read and return its contents, then append some more text to it and finally, read it again and echo the contents.

```
<?php
    $file = "test.txt";

    $fileHandler = fopen($file, "w") or die("Could not write to file!");
    fwrite($fileHandler, "This is my first message <br>");
    fwrite($fileHandler, "This is my second message <br>");
    fclose($fileHandler);


    $fileHandler = fopen($file, "r") or die("Could not read file!");;
    $contents = fread($fileHandler, filesize($file));
    fclose($fileHandler);

    echo $contents;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "FileSize after first write: " . filesize($file);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<hr>";

    $fileHandler = fopen($file, "a") or die("Could not append to file!");
    fwrite($fileHandler, "This is my third message <br>");
    fclose($fileHandler);

    $fileHandler = fopen($file, "r") or die("Could not read file!");;
    $contents = fread($fileHandler, filesize($file));
    fclose($fileHandler);

    echo $contents;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "FileSize after append: " . filesize($file);
    echo "<br>";
```

Everything works as it should be, all messages are written to the file, but the problem is with the echos..
I am expecting to see something like this:

```
This is my test message
This is my second test message

FileSize after first write: 63
-----------------------------------------------------------------
This is my test message
This is my second test message
This is my third test message

FileSize after append: 97
```

but I get the following echo instead:

```
This is my test message
This is my second test message

FileSize after first write: 63
--------------------------------------------------------------------
This is my test message
This is my second test message

FileSize after append: 63
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem here...
Any help would be very much appreciated!!!!

Comment: use a+ instead of a in your second parameter in fopen function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried it and got the same result.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `a+` is used to open a file in *read + write* mode, means it have nothing to do with your problem. Then as already mentioned in the other anwers the function `filesize()` is cached and you need to use `clearstatcache()` in order to see the change.

Alternative to `fopen()` + `fwrite()` + `fclose()` you can use the function `file_put_contents()` which combines the 3 functions.

Example:

```php
    $file = __DIR__.'/test.txt';

    // First we call the function without second parameter
    file_put_contents($file, 'This is my first message'.PHP_EOL);
    // Following calls use the second parameter with FILE_APPEND`
    file_put_contents($file, 'This is my second message'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

    echo file_get_contents($file);
    echo PHP_EOL.'FileSize after first write: ' . filesize($file) . ' bytes' . PHP_EOL;
    clearstatcache();
    echo '-----------------------'.PHP_EOL;

    file_put_contents($file, 'This is my third message'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    echo file_get_contents($file);
    echo PHP_EOL.'FileSize after append: ' . filesize($file) . ' bytes' . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
This is my first message
This is my second message

FileSize after first write: 51 bytes
-----------------------
This is my first message
This is my second message
This is my third message

FileSize after append: 76 bytes
`
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yes, I've read about file_put_contents() while searching for my problem but I wanted to figure out what was the problem with the existing code I had!  :)

Answer (score 2):

In documentation page of [`filesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#refsect1-function.filesize-notes)

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

So you must clear cache after writing new content:

```
 $fileHandler = fopen($file, "a") or die("Could not append to file!");
 fwrite($fileHandler, "This is my third message <br>");
 fclose($fileHandler);
 clearstatcache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write or read a file, PHP caches the changes. So you have to clear the caches.you can use the `clearstatcache()` function to clear the information that PHP caches about a file.

Read more here please https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache